# How to sort database values using other variable

Tags: sort

I am fetching data using the custom slug in craft commerce products but I am not getting the sequence of the products which I am providing in the custom slug

Here is the code for that.

`slugs = "A1,B2,C3";`

`{% set products = craft.commerce.products({slug: slugs}) %}`

Results I am getting

`B2,C3,A1`

I want the results

`A1,B2,C3`

Also, the Split function is not working over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worth mentioning first that Element Queries have a `fixedOrder` parameter available to them (https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/4.x/products-variants.html#product-fixedorder)... however from looking at the docs I think that might only work if you also specify the element IDs instead of slugs. If that's a possibility for your setup it might be the best solution.

If not, then you could instead treat your result set as a hash map/lookup table and loop through your preferred slugs variable something like this (untested):

```twig
{% set slugs = ['A1', 'B2', 'C3'] %}
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.slug(slugs).all() %}
    
<ul>
    {% for slug in slugs %}
        {% set product = products|filter(item => item.slug == slug)[0] %}
        <li>{{ product.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: How can I convert ```{% set slugs = "A1,B2,C3" %}```  to {% set slugs = ['A1', 'B2', 'C3'] %} ? 
Split function is not working

Comment: If the `split` filter isn't working you'll need to figure out why. Try dumping out your input string to see exactly what you have. Where is the string coming from?

Comment: Split function is working now but ```{% set product = products|filter(item => item.slug == slug)[0] %}``` line is showing error about array_filter

Comment: Would need to see the exact error to help. Maybe try removing the `[0]` from the end.